# the latex mark are not shown in the heading of ERDC report

Tags: packages, fancyhdr

I am using a erdc (a modified version which override the mathgifg fonts).
I want to change the header of the report, so it will show the report-number on the inner-side, the the chapter title on the outer-side and the page number on the outer footer.

Here are the short sample code (see below), what I have trying. However, I got some issues:

1. the \rightmark do not have effect, it printed nothing. Even outside the \mainmatter, as the fancyhdr manual suggested.
2. If I include the \reportnum, I got a lot of errors. In this example the statement is commented out.

What do I miss? Please need your advice.

```
\documentclass{erdcx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%% FORMAT OF HEADING
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
%       \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textsf{{\footnotesize\reportnum}}} %inner header
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{{\footnotesize\rightmark}}} %outter header
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textsf{{\footnotesize\thepage}}}   %outter footer

\begin{document}
%       \mainmatter
    \chapter{Primo}
    \thispagestyle{plain} 
    \Blindtext

    \chapter{Secondo} 
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \blindtext
    \blindmathpaper

    \chapter{Terzo}
    \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

I also tried to add the following to the preamble, but no luck.

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
```

Comment: `erdc.cls` is on TeX Live, but the modification isn't.

Comment: you are correct. I have copied the erdc.cls to my local directory. And then, comment the lines related to the fonts like \usepackage{mathgifg} and replace all the \fontseries{k} or {h} with the supported ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `erdc` class defines `\@chapter` *not* to emit `\chaptermark`, so no marks are found.

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \if@frontmatter
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
  \else
      \refstepcounter{chapter}%
      \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
      \if@appendix
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
             {\@chapapp\space\thechapter: #1}%
         \@makechapterhead{\@chapapp\space\thechapter: #2}%
      \else
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
             {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
         \@makechapterhead{\makebox[35\p@]{\thechapter\hfill}#2}%
      \fi
  \fi
  \@afterheading}
```

Here's a patch for it.

```
% don't load mathgifg (does not exist)
\expandafter\def\csname ver@mathgifg.sty\endcsname{}
%%%

\documentclass{erdc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} % latin just to avoid overfull boxes
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}% not needed
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%% FORMAT OF HEADING
%\pagestyle{fancy} % not needed
\fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textsf{{\footnotesize\@reportnum}}} %inner header
\makeatother
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{{\footnotesize\leftmark}}} %outer header
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textsf{{\footnotesize\thepage}}}  %outer footer
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

% patch \@chapter to emit \chaptermark
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\fi\fi}{\fi\chaptermark{#1}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Primo}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\Blindtext

\chapter{Secondo} 
\thispagestyle{plain}

\blindtext
\blindmathpaper

\chapter{Terzo}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm grateful. Wow, looks like this issue stem, deep, from the bowel of the beast. Only a master can see this. I have read the erdc manual, it do mention about the \chapter. I just thought everything that maybe everything can be overrided, like the fonts case, not so. Oh well, back to the kiddy pool for me.